# LinearGradientBrush convertor

Tags: c#

How to convert a LinearGradientBrush value to string value or to color value .? 
I have a method which returns a LinearGradientBrush value

```
    private LinearGradientBrush SetBackground(string color1, string color2)
    {
        LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush();
        brush.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        brush.EndPoint = new Point(0, 1);
        GradientStop gra1 = new GradientStop();
        gra1.Color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(color1);
        gra1.Offset = 1;
        GradientStop gra2 = new GradientStop();
        gra2.Color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(color2);
        gra2.Offset = 0;
        brush.GradientStops.Add(gra1);
        brush.GradientStops.Add(gra2);
        return brush;
    }
```

I need to convert this return value into string type or hexadecimal value such as "FFFF00" representation , Is it possible ,If yes , how to do so ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: A question which I feel needs to be asked first is why do you need to convert this to a string?  Is it for serialisation purposes?  Descriptive purposes?

Comment: yes , its for serialisation purpose .

Answer (score 2):

A relatively simple way of doing this would be to just output various properties to a string.  Working from brain compiler here, but wouldn't it be as easy as:

```
private string LinearGradientBrushToString(LinearGradientBrush brush)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    output.Append(brush.StartPoint.X + "," + brush.StartPoint.Y);
    output.Append("|" + brush.EndPoint.X + "," + brush.EndPoint.Y);

    foreach(GradientStop g in brush.GradientStops) 
    {
        output.Append("|" + g.Offset + "," + ColorConverter.ConvertToString(g.Color));
    }

    return output.ToString();
}
```

That should output a string that has key properties converted to strings and placed in a pipe and comma-delimited format.  Easy enough to use `String.Split()` to break it out and create a brush from it again.

Comment: great , but is it possible to convert the lineargrdientbrush value to a hexadecimal value something like "#fff000".

Comment: Clearly not. The whole point of a linear gradient brush is that it draws a *gradient*. That requires more than one color. But yes, what Adrian suggests is the only solution. Native objects like brushes cannot be serialized directly. Your only option is to save their properties, read them back, and construct a new, similar object.

Answer (score 0):

Look ... a color is a single point of solid color. A linear gradient is a collection of color points. This means that, if you want to compare a point to a rule, you should do some conversion or something like that.

```
public static class LinearGratientBrushExtensions
{
    public static Color AverageColor(this LinearGradientBrush brush)
    {
        return brush.GradientStops[(int)Math.Round((double)((brush.GradientStops.Count() - 1) / 2), 0)].Color;
    }
}
```

The provided extension method uses a simple 'point-in-the-middle' approach, picking up the middle point of the color rule and returnin it. You must choose your own algorithm to find this 'middle point'.